# NOt able to parse "&"

Tags: iphone, xml

My xml consist of words in few different language, Latin words etc.
am able to parse these Latin characters and all except the fact that I am not able parse only "&"

This is what I am getting @gdb

> Entity: line 223: parser error : > xmlParseEntityRef: no name Ull > always be mine 4 now & 4ever.Ull > always be mine 4 u r my treasure.Ull

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ampersand is treated as a special character because it is a special character. Ampersand  is the start of an entity.

Ampersand ("&") needs to [be written as & amp](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#syntax); or be contained in a [CDATA](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#dt-cdsection) section

See this link on [how to escape XML strings in Objective-C](http://inspiredcoding.com/iphonesdk/escaping-xml-characters-in-objective-c/)

Comment: can u let me know about CDATA secion,l'll bit


thanks for reply

Comment: I am not sure if the link provided really solved MY issue with the parser. As far as I understand the code in the "how to escape" link, it returns a non-escaped string from an escaped, correct? So you would pass it something like 'B&ampB' and it would return 'B&B'? I ask, because in my case I have an XML file, which is created by the user manually. So I guess I have to replace those ampersands before parsing by &amp, which is the opposite of the code provided. Is there also anything like that I could do?

Comment: See the [Google Toolbox](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/source/browse/trunk/Foundation/GTMNSString%2BXML.h) or  look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/803676/encode-nsstring-for-xml-html

Answer (score 0):

I used this simple line of code in my case before parsing that xml:

```
cleaned = [original stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"&amp;"];
```

I did use `[NSString stringByDecodingHTMLEntities];` Just before that since my server returns messages with tags.