# HTML Encode an NSString iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios4

I have an rss feed that i am taking the description from using nsxmlparser. This is then output onto a tableview however it is html. is there a way to html encode a string in objective c on the iphone?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encode NSString for XML/HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/803676/encode-nsstring-for-xml-html)