# Decoding HTML entities on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa

I have a list of several locations, some of them containing the letters æ, Æ, ø, Ø, å and Å. 
From the webservice I'm using, the letters comes out as "&oslash ;" "&Aring ;" etc.

When I download the feed from the webservice, I use UTF-8 encoding.

How can I decode the occurences of these characters?

Thanks!

Comment: Think this thread should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/803676/encode-nsstring-for-xml-html

Comment: Get your web service provider to send the feed in non-html-encoded UTF-8.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective C HTML escape/unescape](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659602/objective-c-html-escape-unescape)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard way, to make it simple write your own custom method (or NSString extension) and do this :

```
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&amp;" withString:@"&"];
```

Answer (score 0):

If your webservice is using utf8 and if you decode the data with `[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]`, all should be ok.

Comment: According to his question, his web service is sending html-encoded text. The fact that the stream is UTF-8 is irrelevant. If he creates the string as described here, the `&oslash;` is not going to turn into Ø, it's just going to be the 8 character, UTF-8 encoded string `&oslash;`

Comment: My bad, it's actually the html-encoded wich is the problem, I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

A NSString category called "GTMNSString+HTML" written by Google works perfectly for me. Check it out here: https://gist.github.com/takuma104/ntlniph/blob/master/gtm/Foundation/GTMNSString+HTML.h & here: https://gist.github.com/takuma104/ntlniph/blob/master/gtm/Foundation/GTMNSString+HTML.m