# How to display accented characters entities in a iOS app?

Tags: php, ios, xcode, nsstring, entities

In my iOS app I get data from an external PHP script which builds and returns strings using queries on a mySQL database. In this database, texts have HTML entities in them, e.g. Josè is written as

```
Jos&egrave;
```

When I pass these built strings to my app, all the entities are still there but I'd like to transform them into human readable text in my app. I can't find a way to do this.
I saw questions like **[this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8724128/decoding-html-entities-on-iphone)** with accepted answers **[like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8724198/1065669)** but I can't write a line for any of the hundreds of entities that exist. I mean, I could, but I can't believe there is not a way to do this in a more simple way.

Also, since I use said strings in many places from many views through all the app (text views, labels, table view cells, etc) I think it would VERY useful to apply the correct transformation in the PHP script itself, rather than in the app. So my final question is this: which is the correct way to build a string with entities in it so when I load it in my iOS app all the entities are readable characters? Thank you to ANYONE who will help me!

Comment: In the PHP part you could use html_entity_decode before sending the data.

Comment: This and using NSASCIIStringEncoding seems to have solved my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Google's category  GTMNSString+HTML

This category possibly covers most of the HTML entities you might want to convert into human readable format.

Since I'm not able to find the Google code for this category, I'm pointing to an alternative location; [MWFeedParser](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser).

[GTMNSString+HTML.h](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser/blob/master/Classes/GTMNSString+HTML.h)

[GTMNSString+HTML.m](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser/blob/master/Classes/GTMNSString+HTML.m)