# NSString to HTML

Tags: iphone, html, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I'm showing NSString in a UIWebview to show the text with custom smileys (images) but I got into trouble as UIWebview is not able to detect special characters like \n,\r,\t, whitespaces,&,<,> and many more of the string.How to convert a NSString to HTML string to load in a UIWebView ?

Comment: You can write the whole thing with html tags.. Instead of just strings..

Comment: the string is not static.It is variable so I've to write the algo to convert it into html

Comment: Many more? Which other control characters are you speaking of?

Comment: I don't know right now but it might happen that I missed others as well like whitespaces,&,<,> etc.

Comment: Could you provide some example that you're trying to convert?

Comment: There seems to be a little confusion as to what exact type of conversion you are looking for. \n and \r are newline and carriage return, respectively, while \t is the tab character. This last one can't be converted in simple conversion to HTML. For now, I vote to close so the question can be clarified a bit - then it can be re-opened.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encode NSString for XML/HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/803676/encode-nsstring-for-xml-html)

Answer (score 3):

There's no built in solution for that. You have to encode the HTML entities. There is an open-source project called [NSString-HTML](https://github.com/Koolistov/NSString-HTML#readme) which might suit your needs.

There is also a good NSString category [here](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser/blob/master/Classes/NSString+HTML.h), which is based on [Google's Toolbox](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/).

Comment: the 1st library doesn't solve the problem but it looks like 2nd library might solve my problem.I already saw that library before posting this question but could not figure out the method of my interest

Comment: You might be interested in `stringByEncodingHTMLEntities` (and `stringWithNewLinesAsBRs`).

Answer (score 1):

There is in fact a built in solution for this... In NSAttributedString.  Here is a category for NSString that makes it easy:

```
@interface NSString (HTMLString)
- (NSString *)HTMLString;
@end

@implementation NSString (HTMLString)
- (NSString *)HTMLString {
    NSDictionary * const exportParams = @{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType};
    NSAttributedString *attributed = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self];
    NSData *htmlData = [attributed dataFromRange:NSMakeRange(0, attributed.length) documentAttributes:exportParams error:nil];
    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:htmlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried converting the HTML string to UTF8 format and then load it in the web view?

```
[webView loadData:[html dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                     MIMEType:@\"text/html\"
             textEncodingName:@\"UTF-8\"
                      baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: No wonder You did not understand!! Sorry I understood the question wrongly. I'l do a quick search and edit the answer if I get something.

Comment: @Shubham see if this helps.. sorry again.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for ICU Transformation. 
This functionality is wrapped in the CFString API function CFStringTransform()
Using the transform option Any-Hex
You may want to optimize by creating an NSCharacterSet of only the glyphs that NEED to be escaped.