# Any way to replace characters on Swift String?

Tags: swift, string

I am looking for a way to replace characters in a Swift `String`.

Example: "This is my string"

I would like to replace " " with "+" to get "This+is+my+string".

How can I achieve this?

Comment: [Swift Extension](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39841550/1634890)

Answer (score 1090, accepted):

This answer has been **updated for Swift 4 & 5**. If you're still using Swift 1, 2 or 3 see the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24201206/revisions).

You have a couple of options. You can do [as @jaumard suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24201043) and use `replacingOccurrences()`

```
let aString = "This is my string"
let newString = aString.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "+", options: .literal, range: nil)
```

And as noted by @cprcrack below, the `options` and `range` parameters are optional, so if you don't want to specify string comparison options or a range to do the replacement within, you only need the following.

```
let aString = "This is my string"
let newString = aString.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "+")
```

Or, if the data is in a specific format like this, where you're just replacing separation characters, you can use `components()` to break the string into and array, and then you can use the `join()` function to put them back to together with a specified separator.

```
let toArray = aString.components(separatedBy: " ")
let backToString = toArray.joined(separator: "+")
```

Or if you're looking for a more Swifty solution that doesn't utilize API from NSString, you could use this.

```
let aString = "Some search text"

let replaced = String(aString.map {
    $0 == " " ? "+" : $0
})
```

Comment: **options** and **range** parameters are optional

Comment: I don't know if I'm doing something wrong but the second swift 2.0 solution leaves me with and optional string. Original String looks like this: `"x86_64"` and the new mapping looks like `"Optional([\"x\", \"8\", \"6\", \"_\", \"6\", \"4\"])"`

Comment: @JohnShelley I'm unable to reproduce that. I'm not sure what's going on with the escaping, and this should be using String's `public init(_ characters: String.CharacterView)` initializer, which isn't failable. Are you trying this in a playground? I've had playgrounds give me strange output before that didn't match the output from an actually application.

Comment: Nope, trying in a workspace/project. It might be something I'm doing, but thought I'd leave a comment just in case its common.

Comment: For anyone who had issues with using `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` in Swift 2, you need to `import Foundation` to be able to use that method.

Comment: wow, stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString, how intuitive! I was expecting something like makeNewStringByReplacingOccurrencesOfFirstArgumentByValueInSecondArgument

Comment: For Swift 3, use `let newString = aString.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "+")`

Comment: Don't forget to `import Foundation` if you're doing this in a Playground.

Comment: (Not just Playground. The method is declared in Foundation, not in Swift's standard library.)

Answer (score 74):

You can use this:

```
let s = "This is my string"
let modified = s.replace(" ", withString:"+")
```

If you add this extension method anywhere in your code:

```
extension String
{
    func replace(target: String, withString: String) -> String
    {
       return self.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(target, withString: withString, options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
    }
}
```

Swift 3:

```
extension String
{
    func replace(target: String, withString: String) -> String
    {
        return self.replacingOccurrences(of: target, with: withString, options: NSString.CompareOptions.literal, range: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: I would not name the function "replace" as this suggest it mutates the variable. Use same grammar as Apple do. Calling it "replacing(_:withString:)" makes it much more clear. A future mutating "replace" function would also conflict in naming.

Answer (score 69):

**Swift 3, Swift 4, Swift 5 Solution**

```
let exampleString = "Example string"

//Solution suggested above in Swift 3.0
let stringToArray = exampleString.components(separatedBy: " ")
let stringFromArray = stringToArray.joined(separator: "+")

//Swiftiest solution
let swiftyString = exampleString.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "+")
```

Answer (score 22):

Did you test this :

```
var test = "This is my string"

let replaced = test.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "+", options: nil, range: nil)
```

Answer (score 19):

```
var str = "This is my string"

print(str.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "+"))
```

Output is

```
This+is+my+string
```

Answer (score 15):

**Swift 5.5**

I am using this extension:

```
extension String {

    func replaceCharacters(characters: String, toSeparator: String) -> String {
        let characterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: characters)
        let components = components(separatedBy: characterSet)
        let result = components.joined(separator: toSeparator)
        return result
    }

    func wipeCharacters(characters: String) -> String {
        return self.replaceCharacters(characters: characters, toSeparator: "")
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
"<34353 43434>".replaceCharacters(characters: "< >", toSeparator:"+") // +34353+43434+
"<34353 43434>".wipeCharacters(characters: "< >") // 3435343434
```

Answer (score 12):

Swift 4:

```
let abc = "Hello world"

let result = abc.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "_", 
    options: NSString.CompareOptions.literal, range:nil)

print(result :\(result))
```

Output:

```
result : Hello_world
```

Answer (score 8):

A Swift 3 solution along the lines of Sunkas's:

```
extension String {
    mutating func replace(_ originalString:String, with newString:String) {
        self = self.replacingOccurrences(of: originalString, with: newString)
    }
}
```

Use:

```
var string = "foo!"
string.replace("!", with: "?")
print(string)
```

Output:

```
foo?
```

Answer (score 7):

A category that modifies an existing mutable String:

```
extension String
{
    mutating func replace(originalString:String, withString newString:String)
    {
        let replacedString = self.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(originalString, withString: newString, options: nil, range: nil)
        self = replacedString
    }
}
```

Use:

```
name.replace(" ", withString: "+")
```

Answer (score 7):

Swift 3 solution based on [Ramis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33120336/649379):

```
extension String {
    func withReplacedCharacters(_ characters: String, by separator: String) -> String {
        let characterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: characters)
        return components(separatedBy: characterSet).joined(separator: separator)
    }
}
```

Tried to come up with an appropriate function name according to Swift 3 naming convention.

Comment: This is my preferred solution, as it lets you replace multiple characters at once.

Answer (score 6):

Less happened to me, I just want to change (a word or character) in the `String`

So I've use the `Dictionary`

```
  extension String{
    func replace(_ dictionary: [String: String]) -> String{
          var result = String()
          var i = -1
          for (of , with): (String, String)in dictionary{
              i += 1
              if i<1{
                  result = self.replacingOccurrences(of: of, with: with)
              }else{
                  result = result.replacingOccurrences(of: of, with: with)
              }
          }
        return result
     }
    }
```

usage

```
let mobile = "+1 (800) 444-9999"
let dictionary = ["+": "00", " ": "", "(": "", ")": "", "-": ""]
let mobileResult = mobile.replace(dictionary)
print(mobileResult) // 001800444999
```

Comment: Good solution! 
Thanks

Comment: swift goes out of its way to use different terminology for almost everything. almost any other languages it's just `replace`

Answer (score 5):

```
var str = "This is my string"
str = str.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "+")
print(str)
```

Comment: why can I not find `replacingOccurrences` in `String` ?

Comment: Mack sure your variable type is String

Answer (score 4):

**Xcode 11 • Swift 5.1**

The  mutating method of StringProtocol `replacingOccurrences` can be implemented as follow:

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection where Self: StringProtocol {
    mutating func replaceOccurrences<Target: StringProtocol, Replacement: StringProtocol>(of target: Target, with replacement: Replacement, options: String.CompareOptions = [], range searchRange: Range<String.Index>? = nil) {
        self = .init(replacingOccurrences(of: target, with: replacement, options: options, range: searchRange))
    }
}
```

---

```
var name = "This is my string"
name.replaceOccurrences(of: " ", with: "+")
print(name) // "This+is+my+string\n"
```

Comment: This is a great little tidbit. Thanks Leo!

Answer (score 3):

This is easy in swift 4.2. just use `replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "_")` for replace

```
var myStr = "This is my string"
let replaced = myStr.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "_")
print(replaced)
```

Answer (score 3):

Since Swift 2, `String` does no longer conform to `SequenceType`. In other words, you can not iterate through a string with a `for...in` loop.

The simple and easy way is to convert `String` to `Array` to get the benefit of the index just like that:

```
let input = Array(str)
```

I remember when I tried to index into `String` without using any conversion. I was really frustrated that I couldn’t come up with or reach a desired result, and was about to give up.
But I ended up creating my own workaround solution, and here is the full code of the extension:

```
extension String {
    subscript (_ index: Int) -> String {
    
        get {
             String(self[self.index(startIndex, offsetBy: index)])
        }
    
        set {
            remove(at: self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: index))
            insert(Character(newValue), at: self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: index))
        }
    }
}
```

Now that you can read and replace a single character from string using its index just like you originally wanted to:

```
var str = "cat"
for i in 0..<str.count {
 if str[i] == "c" {
   str[i] = "h"
 }
}

print(str)
```

It’s simple and useful way to use it and get through Swift’s String access model.
Now that you’ll feel it’s smooth sailing next time when you can loop through the string just as it is, not casting it into `Array`.

Try it out, and see if it can help!

Answer (score 2):

I've implemented this very simple func:

```
func convap (text : String) -> String {
    return text.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("'", withString: "''")
}
```

So you can write:

```
let sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO myTable (Field1, Field2) VALUES ('\(convap(value1))','\(convap(value2)')
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the example for Swift 3:

```
var stringToReplace = "This my string"
if let range = stringToReplace.range(of: "my") {
   stringToReplace?.replaceSubrange(range, with: "your")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting from `iOS 16` We could use new method on `RangeReplaceableCollection` [`replace(_:with:maxReplacements:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/rangereplaceablecollection/replace(_:with:maxreplacements:)-20ctz), that uses `Regex` as a parameter, where we can customize our request.

```
var myString = "This is my string"
myString.replace(" ", with: "+")
```

But don't forget to `import RegexBuilder` to enable this

Answer (score 1):

I think Regex is the most flexible and solid way:

```
var str = "This is my string"
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: " ", options: [])
let output = regex.stringByReplacingMatchesInString(
    str,
    options: [],
    range: NSRange(location: 0, length: str.characters.count),
    withTemplate: "+"
)
// output: "This+is+my+string"
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift extension:**

```
extension String {

    func stringByReplacing(replaceStrings set: [String], with: String) -> String {
        var stringObject = self
        for string in set {
            stringObject = self.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(string, withString: with)
        }
        return stringObject
    }

}
```

Go on and use it like `let replacedString = yorString.stringByReplacing(replaceStrings: [" ","?","."], with: "+")`

The speed of the function is something that i can hardly be proud of, but you can pass an array of `String` in one pass to make more than one replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an extension for an in-place occurrences replace method on `String`, that doesn't no an unnecessary copy and do everything in place:

```
extension String {
    mutating func replaceOccurrences<Target: StringProtocol, Replacement: StringProtocol>(of target: Target, with replacement: Replacement, options: String.CompareOptions = [], locale: Locale? = nil) {
        var range: Range<Index>?
        repeat {
            range = self.range(of: target, options: options, range: range.map { self.index($0.lowerBound, offsetBy: replacement.count)..<self.endIndex }, locale: locale)
            if let range = range {
                self.replaceSubrange(range, with: replacement)
            }
        } while range != nil
    }
}
```

(The method signature also mimics the signature of the built-in `String.replacingOccurrences()` method)

May be used in the following way:

```
var string = "this is a string"
string.replaceOccurrences(of: " ", with: "_")
print(string) // "this_is_a_string"
```

Comment: I've updated the code to prevent infinite loops if the contained text was contained in the target text.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5.5**

But this might work in earlier versions.

I'm frequently replacing because I want to replace "any whitespace or -" with a _ or something like that. This extension on string lets me do that.

```
extension String {
    func removingCharacters(_ characters:CharacterSet) -> Self {
        Self(self.unicodeScalars.filter {
            !characters.contains($0)
        })
    }
    func removingCharacters(in string:String) -> Self {
        Self(self.unicodeScalars.filter {
            !CharacterSet(charactersIn:string).contains($0)
        })
    }
    
    func replacingCharacters(_ characters:CharacterSet, with newChar:Character) -> Self {
        String(self.compactMap( {
            CharacterSet(charactersIn: "\($0.1)").isSubset(of: characters)
             ? newChar : $0.1
        }))
    }
    
    func replacingCharacters(in string:String, with newChar:Character) -> Self {
        String(self.compactMap( {
            CharacterSet(charactersIn: "\($0)").isSubset(of: CharacterSet(charactersIn:string))
             ? newChar : $0
        }))
    }
}
```

usage:

```
print("hello \n my name\t is Joe".removingCharacters(.whitespacesAndNewlines))
print("hello \n my name\t is Joe".removingCharacters(in: " \t\n"))

print("ban annan anann ana".replacingCharacters(.whitespacesAndNewlines, with: "_"))
print("ban-annan anann ana".replacingCharacters(in: " -", with: "_"))
```

Obviously for a single character the `.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "+")` is better.

I have not done a performance comparison to the

```
let toArray = aString.components(separatedBy: characterSet)
let backToString = toArray.joined(separator: "+")
```

style done in Ramis's extension.  I'd be interested if someone does.

See also replacing emoji's: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63416058/5946596

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the Objective-C `NSString` methods, you can just use `split` and `join`:

```
var string = "This is my string"
string = join("+", split(string, isSeparator: { $0 == " " }))
```

`split(string, isSeparator: { $0 == " " })` returns an array of strings (`["This", "is", "my", "string"]`).

`join` joins these elements with a `+`, resulting in the desired output: `"This+is+my+string"`.

Answer (score 0):

you can test this:

```
let newString = test.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "+", options: nil, range: nil)
```