# Swift - Replacing emojis in a string with whitespace

Tags: string, swift, unicode, emoji

I have a method that detects urls in a string and returns me both the urls and the ranges where they can be found. Everything works perfectly until there are emojis on the string. For example:

```
"I'm gonna do this callenge as soon as I can swing again \n http://youtu.be/SW_d3fGz1hk"
```

Because of the emojis, the url extracted from the text is http://youtu.be/SW_d3fGz1 instead of http://youtu.be/SW_d3fGz1hk. I figured that the easiest solution was to just replace the emojis on the string with whitespace characters (cause I need the range to be correct for some text styling stuff). Problem is, this is extremely hard to accomplish with Swift (most likely my abilities with the Swift String API is lacking).

I've been trying to do it like this but it seems that I cannot create a string from an array of unicode points:

```
var emojilessStringWithSubstitution: String {
    let emojiRanges = [0x1F601...0x1F64F, 0x2702...0x27B0]
    let emojiSet = Set(emojiRanges.flatten())
    let codePoints: [UnicodeScalar] = self.unicodeScalars.map {
        if emojiSet.contains(Int($0.value)) {
            return UnicodeScalar(32)
        }
        return $0
    }
    return String(codePoints)
}
```

Am I approaching this problem the wrong way? Is replacing emojis the best solution here? If so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use pattern matching (for emoji patterns) to filter out emoji characters from your `String`.

```
extension String {

    var emojilessStringWithSubstitution: String {
        let emojiPatterns = [UnicodeScalar(0x1F601)...UnicodeScalar(0x1F64F),
                             UnicodeScalar(0x2702)...UnicodeScalar(0x27B0)]
        return self.unicodeScalars
            .filter { ucScalar in !(emojiPatterns.contains{ $0 ~= ucScalar }) }
            .reduce("") { $0 + String($1) }
    }  
}

/* example usage */
let str = "I'm gonna do this callenge as soon as I can swing again \n http://youtu.be/SW_d3fGz1hk"
print(str.emojilessStringWithSubstitution)

/* I'm gonna do this callenge as soon as I can swing again
   http://youtu.be/SW_d3fGz1hk */
```

Note that the above only makes use of the emoji intervals as presented in your question, and is in no way representative for all emojis, but the method is general and can swiftly be extended by including additional emoji intervals to the `emojiPatterns` array.

---

I realize reading your question again that you'd prefer substituting emojis with whitespace characters, rather than removing them (which the above filtering solution does). We can achieve this by replacing the `.filter` operation above with a conditional return `.map` operation instead, much like in your question

```
extension String {

    var emojilessStringWithSubstitution: String {
        let emojiPatterns = [UnicodeScalar(0x1F600)...UnicodeScalar(0x1F64F),
                         UnicodeScalar(0x1F300)...UnicodeScalar(0x1F5FF),
                         UnicodeScalar(0x1F680)...UnicodeScalar(0x1F6FF),
                         UnicodeScalar(0x2600)...UnicodeScalar(0x26FF),
                         UnicodeScalar(0x2700)...UnicodeScalar(0x27BF),
                         UnicodeScalar(0xFE00)...UnicodeScalar(0xFE0F)]

        return self.unicodeScalars
            .map { ucScalar in
                emojiPatterns.contains{ $0 ~= ucScalar } ? UnicodeScalar(32) : ucScalar }
            .reduce("") { $0 + String($1) }
    }
}
```

I the above, the existing emoji intervals has been extended, as per your comment to this post (listing these intervals), such that the emoji check is now possibly exhaustive.

Comment: Almost! The string "Svsbsvs shsbsv \nhttp://m.youtube.com/watch?v=H6_zvQQ5P8w"  results in: "Svsbsvs shsbsv     \nhttp://m.youtube.com/watch?v=H6_zvQQ5P8w"

Comment: Figured it out. I was missing some ranges:
et emojiPatterns = [UnicodeScalar(0x1F600)...UnicodeScalar(0x1F64F),
                             UnicodeScalar(0x1F300)...UnicodeScalar(0x1F5FF),
                             UnicodeScalar(0x1F680)...UnicodeScalar(0x1F6FF),
                             UnicodeScalar(0x2600)...UnicodeScalar(0x26FF),
                             UnicodeScalar(0x2700)...UnicodeScalar(0x27BF),
                             UnicodeScalar(0xFE00)...UnicodeScalar(0xFE0F)

Comment: Ah yes, I should've included in my answer that I simply applied the emoji ranges from your question, and explainef the technique for using these in my answer, however in no way knowing if the ranges were exhaustive! Thanks for your edit!

Comment: @dfri Swift 4.1 `let emojiPatterns = [UnicodeScalar(0x1F601)!...UnicodeScalar(0x1F64F)!, UnicodeScalar(0x2702)!...UnicodeScalar(0x27B0)!]`

Comment: @LeoDabus thanks! I tried a quick edit to the solution above but ran into "expression too complex" for the `emojiPatterns` in the second block (`6` patterns). Seems silly and almost like a regression, but will try to look into re-factoring into something that the compiler can handle if I have some time over.

Answer (score 20):

**Swift 5**

Don't use this `hardcoded` way to detect `emojis`. In `Swift 5` you can do it easily

```
let inputText = "Some string  with   emoji "

let textWithoutEmoij = inputText.unicodeScalars
    .filter { !$0.properties.isEmojiPresentation }
    .reduce("") { $0 + String($1) }

print(textWithoutEmoij) // Some string  with   emoji
```

Comment: This won't be useful if your app supported iOS 10.0

Comment: What are the apps that support 10.0 in ios 14.0 era?? !!

Comment: I don't think we need the `reduce()`. It seems to work if I just pass the results of `filter()` into a String constructor.

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 4:**

```
extension String {
  func stringByRemovingEmoji() -> String {
    return String(self.filter { !$0.isEmoji() })
  }
}

extension Character {
  fileprivate func isEmoji() -> Bool {
    return Character(UnicodeScalar(UInt32(0x1d000))!) <= self && self <= Character(UnicodeScalar(UInt32(0x1f77f))!)
      || Character(UnicodeScalar(UInt32(0x2100))!) <= self && self <= Character(UnicodeScalar(UInt32(0x26ff))!)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Emojis are classified as symbols by Unicode. Character sets are typically used in searching operations. So we will use Character sets a property that is symbols.

```
var emojiString =  "Hey there , welcome"
emojiString = emojiString.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.symbols).joined()       
print(emojiString)
```

Output is

```
Hey there , welcome
```

Now observe the emoji is replaced by a white space so there is two white space and we replace it by the following way

```
emojiString.replacingOccurrences(of: "  ", with: " ")
```

The above method replace parameter of: "two white space" to with: "single white space"

Answer (score 3):

Getting all emoji is more complicated than you would think. For more info on how to figure out which characters are emoji, check out this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30757193/find-out-if-character-in-string-is-emoji/39425959?noredirect=1#comment103592550_39425959) post or [this article](https://medium.com/@krmblr/understanding-swift-strings-characters-and-scalars-a4b82f2d8fde).

Building on that information, I would propose to use the extension on Character to more easily let us understand which characters are emoji. Then add a String extension to easily replace found emoji with another character.

```
extension Character {
   var isSimpleEmoji: Bool {
      guard let firstProperties = unicodeScalars.first?.properties else {
        return false
      }
      return unicodeScalars.count == 1 &&
          (firstProperties.isEmojiPresentation ||
             firstProperties.generalCategory == .otherSymbol)
   }
   var isCombinedIntoEmoji: Bool {
      return unicodeScalars.count > 1 &&
             unicodeScalars.contains {
                $0.properties.isJoinControl ||
                $0.properties.isVariationSelector
             }
   }
   var isEmoji: Bool {
      return isSimpleEmoji || isCombinedIntoEmoji
   }
}

extension String {
    func replaceEmoji(with character: Character) -> String {
        return String(map { $0.isEmoji ? character : $0 })
    }
}
```

Using it would simply become:

```
"Some string  with emoji".replaceEmoji(with: " ")
```

Comment: Doesn't work with flags it appears 

Answer (score 0):

I found that the solutions given above did not work for certain characters such as ️‍♂️ and .

To find the emoji ranges, using regex I converted the [full list of emoji characters](https://unicode.org/Public/emoji/12.0/emoji-test.txt) to a file with just hex values. Then I converted them to decimal format and sorted them. Finally, I wrote a script to find the ranges.

Here is the final Swift extension for `isEmoji()`.

```
extension Character {

    func isEmoji() -> Bool {
        let emojiRanges = [
            (8205, 11093),
            (12336, 12953),
            (65039, 65039),
            (126980, 129685)
        ]
        let codePoint = self.unicodeScalars[self.unicodeScalars.startIndex].value
        for emojiRange in emojiRanges {
            if codePoint >= emojiRange.0 && codePoint <= emojiRange.1 {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }

}
```

For reference, here are the python scripts I wrote to parse the hex strings to integers and then find the ranges.

**convert-hex-to-decimal.py**

```
decimals = []
with open('hex.txt') as hexfile:
    for line in hexfile:
        num = int(line, 16)
        if num < 256:
            continue
        decimals.append(num)

decimals = list(set(decimals))
decimals.sort()

with open('decimal.txt', 'w') as decimalfile:
    for decimal in decimals:
        decimalfile.write(str(decimal) + "\n")
```

**make-ranges.py**

```
first_line = True
range_start = 0
prev = 0
with open('decimal.txt') as hexfile:
    for line in hexfile:
        if first_line: 
            prev = int(line)
            range_start = prev
            first_line = False
            continue

        curr = int(line)
        if prev + 1000 < curr: # 100 is abitrary to reduce number of ranges
            print("(" + str(range_start) + ", " + str(prev) + ")")
            range_start = curr
        prev = curr
```

Comment: Looks promising but a few false positives `’` , `—`

Answer (score 0):

This Swift 5 snippet works like a charm for me, but I haven't checked agains all emoji/symbols. However it's still displaying chinese, korean etc which my previous solution struggled with.

```
extension String {
    // works with unicode languages like korean
    func removeEmojis() -> String {
        return .init(
            unicodeScalars.filter {
                $0.properties.isEmojiPresentation == false &&
                $0.properties.isEmoji == false
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Don't hard-code the range of emojis, use this instead.

```
func 去除表情符号(字符串:String) -> String {
    let 转换为Unicode = 字符串.unicodeScalars//https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string
    
    let 去除表情后的结果 = 转换为Unicode.filter { (item) -> Bool in
        let 判断是否表情 = item.properties.isEmoji
         return !判断是否表情//是表情就不保留
      }
    
    return String(去除表情后的结果)
}
```