# How to remove special characters in Swift 3

Tags: swift, special-characters

How to remove any special characters in a string?
Example: ,  or  in string with Swift 3.

I try to remove them with:

```
.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\u{+}", with: "", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift - Replacing emojis in a string with whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36919125/swift-replacing-emojis-in-a-string-with-whitespace)

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "special characters"? Just Emoji characters? What about math symbols? What about Cyrillic? Or Arabic? Or Chinese? Or anything else? Update your question with actual code showing real strings you wish to update. Show the desired results and your actual results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Working in Swift 4.1

```
import Foundation

extension String {
    var withoutSpecialCharacters: String {
        return self.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.symbols).joined(separator: "")
    }
}
```