# Swift - iOS: Remove spaces inside a String before or after any special character

Tags: ios, swift

I have to do validation to check user entered answer to an application. I want to remove spaces (if any) **left** or **before** for bellow special characters.

> - **/**
> - **,**
> - **:**
> - **;**
> - **-**
> - **.**

So the final output should be like this.

Ex:

> Correct answer => a/b
>
> Answers need to accept => ' a/b ', 'a/ b', 'a /b', 'a/ b ', 'a/b   '

I can do this using replacingOccurrences function by replacing all possible values. Is there any better solution for this?

Comment: can you show some sample inputs

Comment: Ex: ' apple / orange', 'apple  /orange ', 'apple / orange ', '  apple /  orange',  => These values need to convert to 'apple/orange'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove whitespaces in strings in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28548908/how-to-remove-whitespaces-in-strings-in-swift)

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: @RakeshaShastri I don't want to trim the string. I need to remove spaces on or before above mentioned special characters (Inside a string).

Comment: What happens if there is more whitespaces than one? `a_/_____b`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can using regular expression for replace the string with format `[ ]+{special_char}` and `{special_char}[ ]+`.

**Edit**

Update `"."` to `"\\."`

Thanks [ielyamani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2907715/ielyamani)

For example

```
func acceptedAnswer(of answer: String) -> String {
    let specialChars = ["/", ":", ",", ";", "-", "\\."]
    var newAnswer = answer.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    for specialChar in specialChars {
        let beforeCharRegex = "[ ]+" + specialChar
        let afterCharRegex = specialChar + "[ ]+"
        newAnswer = newAnswer.replacingOccurrences(of: beforeCharRegex, with: specialChar, options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
        newAnswer = newAnswer.replacingOccurrences(of: afterCharRegex, with: specialChar, options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
    }
    return newAnswer
}

print(acceptedAnswer(of: " apple /   orange     : banana    "))
// apple/orange:banana
```

Comment: I checked your answer. But if there any space between words this solution will not work. Ex: " Apple / Green orange" => Answer should be "Apple/Green orange" - But in your solution answer will be "Apple/Orance.anana"

Comment: @sameera Use `"\\."` instead of `"."`

Comment: @sameera Sorry about it, updated answer with suggestion from  ielyamani

Answer (score 0):

Remove before and after space of Special character using `Range` -

```
    let specialChars = ["/",":", ",", ";", "-", "."]
    let aString = " AB / CD EF ; G : H , MN O - P"
    var trimmedString = aString.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)

    for specialChar in specialChars {

        if let beforeSpacerange = trimmedString.range(of: " \(specialChar)") {
            trimmedString.replaceSubrange(beforeSpacerange, with: specialChar)
        }
        if let afterSpacerange = trimmedString.range(of: "\(specialChar) ") {
            trimmedString.replaceSubrange(afterSpacerange, with: specialChar)
        }

    }

    debugPrint(trimmedString)
```

Hope it will help you. Let me know if you are still having any issue.

Happy coding.

Comment: I checked your answer, But I don't need to replace all spaces inside the string. I need to replace spaces which are after or before above special characters. Ex: " Apple / Orance Banana" => "Apple/Orance Banana"

Comment: You need to read the question again since you have clearly misunderstood it. Not all spaces should be removed, please improve your answer.

Comment: My bad I got that wrong. @JoakimDanielson I've updated my answer. Please check.

Comment: This answer is more optimised than accepted answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replacingOccurrences` which would replace your symbol with whitespaces with just this symbol. For this purpose you can use recursive method

```
func removed(in text: String) -> String {
    let symbols = ["/", ",", ":", ";", "-", "."]
    var newText = text
    symbols.forEach { newText = replaced(in: newText, for: $0) }
    return newText
}

func replaced(in text: String, for symbol: String) -> String {
    var newText = text
    let left = " \(symbol)"
    newText = newText.replacingOccurrences(of: left, with: symbol)
    let right = "\(symbol) "
    newText = newText.replacingOccurrences(of: right, with: symbol)
    return newText != text ? replaced(in: newText, for: symbol) : newText
}
```

Usage:

```
let string = "Apple / Orange Swift    .   ObjC Moon  : Sun USA - UK"
print(removed(in: string))
```

> ```
> Apple/Orange Swift.ObjC Moon:Sun USA-UK
> ```