# Is there an equivalent to the string function String(format: ...) using Swift formatting

Tags: string, swift

I'm starting to like the Swift string formatting since it uses variable names in the string rather than ambiguous formatting tags like "%@"

I want to load a large string from a file that has Swift-style formatting in it (like this)

```
Now is the time for all good \(who) to come to babble incoherently.
```

Then I want to feed the contents of that String  variable into a statement that lest me replace

```
\(who)
```

with the contents of the constant/variable who at runtime.

The code below works with a string constant as the formatting string.

```
let who = "programmers"
let aString = "Now is the time for all good \(who) to come to babble incoherently."
```

That code does formatting of a quoted string that appears in-line in my code.

Instead I want something like the code

```
let formatString = "Now is the time for all good %@ to come to babble incoherently."
aString = String(format: formatString, who)
```

#### *But where I can pass in a Swift-style format string in a constant/variable I read from a file.*

Is that possible? I didn't have any luck searching for it since I wasn't exactly sure what search terms to use.

I can always use C-style string formatting and the String class' initWithFormat method if I have to...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to do this.  String interpolation is implemented via conforming to the `StringInterpolationConvertible` protocol, and presumably you're hoping to tap into that in the same way you can tap into the methods required by `StringLiteralConvertible`, a la:

```
let someString = toString(42)

// this is the method String implements to conform to StringLiteralConvertible
let anotherString = String(stringLiteral: someString)

// anotherString will be "42"
print(anotherString)
```

Unfortunately, you can't do quite the same trick with `StringInterpolationConvertible`.  Seeing how the protocol works may help:

```
struct MyString: Printable {
    let actualString: String
    var description: String { return actualString }
}

extension MyString: StringInterpolationConvertible {
    // first, this will get called for each "segment"
    init<T>(stringInterpolationSegment expr: T) {
        println("Processing segment: " + toString(expr))
        actualString = toString(expr)
    }
    // here is a type-specific override for Int, that coverts
    // small numbers into words:
    init(stringInterpolationSegment expr: Int) {
        if (0..<4).contains(expr) {
            println("Embigening \(expr)")
            let numbers = ["zeo","one","two","three"]
            actualString = numbers[expr]
        }
        else {
            println("Processing segment: " + toString(expr))
            actualString = toString(expr)
        }
    }
    // finally, this gets called with an array of all of the
    // converted segments
    init(stringInterpolation strings: MyString...) {
        // strings will be a bunch of MyString objects
        actualString = "".join(strings.map { $0.actualString })
    }
}

let number = 3
let aString: MyString = "Then shalt thou count to \(number), no more, no less."
println(aString)
// prints "Then shalt thou count to three, no more, no less."
```

So, while you can call `String.init(stringInterpolation:)` and `String.init(stringInterpolationSegment:)` directly yourself if you want (just try `String(stringInterpolationSegment: 3.141)` and `String(stringInterpolation: "blah", "blah")`), this doesn't really help you much.  What you really need is a facade function that coordinates the calls to them.  And unless there's a handy pre-existing function in the standard library that does exactly that which I've missed, I think you're out of luck.  I suspect it's built into the compiler.

You could maybe write your own to achieve your goal, but a lot of effort since you'd have to break up the string you want to interpolate manually into bits and handle it yourself, calling the segment `init` in a loop.  Also you'll hit problems with calling the combining function, since you can't splat an array into a variadic function call.

Comment: Thanks Airspeed. That's what I figured, but thought it was worth asking. Pity, since the Swift string formatting syntax has named parameters. It would make your intent much clearer than a big string glob with tons of `%@`s and such in it.

Comment: I agree, it'd be nice.  Maybe file a radar, you never know.  Also I would guess they'll expand interpolation to cover more formatting in future so probably worth getting requests in.

Comment: I'd put a higher priority on things like making NSDates comparable equatable and being able to list tuple constants in the cases of a switch statement. I've written extensions to accomplish both, but it seems to me those should be baked into the language.

Comment: ...Actually, I think **YOU** wrote the code that lets me use tuple constants in switch statements. I should really have said "I have found extensions..."

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. The compiler needs to be able to resolve the interpolated variable at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Swift programmer, specifically, but I think you can workaround it to something pretty close to what you want using a [Dictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID113) and standard string-replacing and splitting methods:

```
var replacement = [String: String]()
replacement["who"] = "programmers"
```

Having that, you can try to find the occurrences of "\(", reading what is next and prior to a ")", ([this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678373/swift-split-a-string-into-an-array) can help with the *split* part, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24200888/any-way-to-replace-characters-on-swift-string), with the replacing part), finding it in the dictionary, and reconstructing your string from the pieces you get.

Answer (score -1):

this one works like a charm:

```
let who = "programmers"
let formatString = "Now is the time for all good %@ to come to babble incoherently."
let aString = String(format: formatString, who)
```

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. I'm asking if there is a way to do that using Swift-style string formatting, like `"Now is the time for all good \(personClass) to babble incoherently."`

Comment: AFAIK - no, because of named variables.
What's wrong with above?

Comment: Well, it's the whole point of my question. Go back and reread my question. I state the goal clearly.