# Using Text field in Swift

Tags: swift, variables, textfield

I have a text field and button to search on XIB.

- For example:  i write "house of sun" on text field

  How can i catch this sentence (house of sun) and transform into a variable
  and put "%20" on the spaces between the words ?

For the variable return for me (house%20of%20sun)

Comment: textField.text to get the text and refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24200888/any-way-to-replace-characters-on-swift-string for replacing characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward:

```
var myString = "house of sun"

var myNewString = myString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "%20", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
```

Where var would be:

```
yourTextFieldName.text
```