# How to remove whitespace in String using pure Swift?

Tags: string, swift

Now, I'm practicing the Swift Language.

I created a `StringHelper` Class.

It saves a string in the `str` property, and by using a method, it returns same string without whitespace.

```
class StringHelper {

    let str:String

    init(str:String) {
        self.str = str
    }

    func removeSpace() -> String {
        //how to code
    }
}


let myStr = StringHelper(str: "hello swift")

myStr.removeSpace()//it should print  'helloswift'
```

**I want to use only the Swift language... not the `NSString` methods**, because I'm just practicing using Swift.

Comment: you can use this: `return str.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")` at the line of `//how to code`

Comment: @DánielNagy `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` is cool but it's an NSString method. OP wants pure Swift.

Comment: @EricD. you are right, that is not good in this case

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any way to replace characters on Swift String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24200888/any-way-to-replace-characters-on-swift-string)

Answer (score 8):

Here's a functional approach using `filter`:

**Swift 1.2**:

```
let str = "  remove  spaces please "

let newstr = String(filter(Array(str), {$0 != " "}))
println(newstr)  // prints "removespacesplease"
```

**Swift 2/3**:

```
let newstr = String(str.characters.filter {$0 != " "})
print(newstr)
```

The idea is to break the `String` into an array of `Character`s, and then use `filter` to remove all `Character`s which are not a space `" "`, and then create a new string from the array using the `String()` initializer.

---

If you want to also remove newlines `"\n"` and tabs `"\t"`, you can use `contains`:

**Swift 1.2**:

```
let newstr = String(filter(Array(str), {!contains([" ", "\t", "\n"], $0)}))
```

**Swift 2/3**:

```
let newstr = String(str.characters.filter {![" ", "\t", "\n"].contains($0)})
```

Answer (score 0):

A more generic version of this questions [exists here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24200888/any-way-to-replace-characters-on-swift-string), so here's an implementation of what you're after:

```
func removeSpace() -> String {
    let whitespace = " "
    let replaced = String(map(whitespace.generate()) {
        $0 == " " ? "" : $0
    })
    return replaced
}
```

If you prefer brevity:

```
func removeSpace() -> String {
    return String(map(" ".generate()) { $0 == " " ? "" : $0 })
}
```

---

Or, if you're using *Swift 2*:

```
func removeSpace() -> String {
    let whitespace = " "
    let replaced = String(whitespace.characters.map {
        $0 == " " ? "" : $0
    })
    return replaced
}
```

Again, more concisely:

```
func removeSpace() -> String {
    return String(" ".characters.map { $0 == " " ? "" : $0 })
}
```