# How to check for multiple whitespaces in a string

Tags: swift

How can I check if a string contains more than one whitespace or period?

I´m using `myString.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: ".")` to change  comma to period, is there a similar function to remove whitespaces, or any other character of choice if they occur more than once?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove whitespace in String using pure Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32269373/how-to-remove-whitespace-in-string-using-pure-swift)

Answer (score 1):

Use Regular Expression, this removes all occurrences of two or more consecutive whitespaces or periods

```
myString.replacingOccurrences(of: "[\\s.]{2,}", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
```

or if you want to keep one whitespace or period respectively you need two filter expressions

```
myString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\s{2,}", with: " ", options: .regularExpression)
    .replacingOccurrences(of: "\\.{2,}", with: ".", options: .regularExpression)
```

In Swift 5.7+ the syntax has become much cleaner

```
myString.replacing(/[\s.]{2,}/, with: "")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace whitespace with 'a' using the following code:-

myString.replacingOccurrences(of: " " , with: "a")

Comment: I want to allow one white space, and/or one period. This will remove all whitespaces