# Replace just the first character in a string | Swift

Tags: arrays, string, swift, replace, range

I'm trying to replace the just first character of a string. Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24200888/any-way-to-replace-characters-on-swift-string#), I'm able to replace all current characters with the one I want, but what I really need is to only replace the character if it's at the start of a word.

---

**For example, replace c with t:**

Original String: Jack is cool
New Sting: Jack is tool

---

**My Current Code:**

```
let aString: String = "jack is cool"
let toArray: Array = aString.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
let newString: String = aString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("c", withString: "t", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
```

This would print out as:

```
"jatk is tool"
```

I assume I have to do something with the range attribute in the newString.

Comment: You've got some issues with your post... Your example doesn't actually follow what you're saying you want to do.

Comment: @ChrisSlowik You are right.

Comment: @MicahCowell BTW please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678373/swift-split-a-string-into-an-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `regex`. `\\b` called word boundary which matches between a word character and a non-word character. You may also use negative lookbehind instead of `\\b` like `(?<!\\S)c`

```
var regex:NSRegularExpression = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\bc", options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.CaseInsensitive, error: &ierror)!
var modString = regex.stringByReplacingMatchesInString(myString, options: nil, range: NSMakeRange(0, stringlength), withTemplate: "t")
```

Answer (score 0):

var aString = 'jack is cool';
var newString = aString.replace('c','t');

Comment: This will replace "c" in "jack" too

Answer (score 0):

var a

```js
var oldString = 'Jack is cool';
var newString = oldString.split(' ');
var x = newString[newString.indexOf('cool')].toString();
x = x.replace('c','t');
newString.splice(newString.indexOf('cool'),1,x);
newString = newString.join(' ').toString();
alert(newString);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your range to start and end at the startIndex to make sure it replaces only occurences at the first character of the string:

```
let coolString = "Cool"
let newString = coolString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("C", withString: "T", options: [], range: coolString.startIndex...coolString.startIndex)
```

You can use String method replace() to replace only the first character of a String

```
var str = "Cool"
str.replaceRange(str.startIndex...str.startIndex, with: "T")
print(str)  // "Tool"
```

To apply it only to the last word:

```
var str = "Jack is Cool"
var words = str.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")

if !words.isEmpty {
    if !words[words.count-1].isEmpty {
        words[words.count-1].replaceRange(str.startIndex...str.startIndex, with: "T")
        print( words.last!)  // "Tool\n"
    }
}
let sentence = words.joinWithSeparator(" ")   // "Jack is Tool"
```

Comment: Just apply it to your array last component