# Swift: insertContentsOf

Tags: string, swift, replace

I'm trying to use inertContentsOf to loop through and find all "\" characters and insert another "\" character in front of it. The problem is I won't always know the index if the character I need to insert.

For example, I know I want to insert "\" at index 3:

`myString.insertContentsOf("\\".characters, at: myString.startIndex.advancedBy(3))`

How would I do this without knowing the index?
I've tried the following for loops but haven't had any luck.

```
for words in inputArray {
    for char in words {
        if char == "\\" {
            words.insertContentsOf("\\".characters, at: char)
        }
    }
}
```

`at: char` yells at me for trying to convert a character to an index, which I get but don't know how to fix it.

Edit: For some reason when I try and put it in a function `inputArray.map` doesn't get called.

```
func GenerateString(inputArray:[String])->String {

inputArray.map {
    $0.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\", withString: "\\\\")
}

let joiner = "|"
let joinerString = inputArray.joinWithSeparator(joiner)

return ("Result: \(joinerString)")
}

let example = ["hello", "world", "c:\Program File\Example"]
GenerateString(example)
```

Result:

> "Hello|world|c:\Program File\Example"

Comment: what will be your input string ? and what output you want ?

Comment: input: "hello" , "world", "c\Program Files\Example". output: "hello world c\\Program Files\\Example".

Comment: I see you edit your question with `map`, be careful `map` return a new array, not change the current one

Compiler could remove this useless code if you don't keep the return array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` instead:

```
words.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\", withString: "\\\\")
```

Comment: Awesome, this worked. It took me a while to get it to run in terminal. you need to import Foundation before you can use stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString.

Comment: @Wrenzoe argh, yes, sorry for that one :/ I always forget about the imports.

Answer (score 1):

Try `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString`:

```
var words: String = "c\\Program Files\\Example"
words = words.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\", withString: "\\\\")
print("Result: \(words)")
// "Result: c\\Program Files\\Example"
```

or if you want to do this in a array:

```
let inputArray: [String] = ["hello", "world", "c\\Program Files\\Example"]
inputArray.map {
    $0.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\", withString: "\\\\")
}
print("Result: \(inputArray)")
// "Result: ["hello", "world", "c\\Program Files\\Example"]"
```

`stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\", withString: "\\\\")` line means replace `\\` with `\\\\` and it's exactly what you want to do. :)

*Related Questions: [Any way to replace characters on Swift String?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24200888/2603230)*

Comment: Be careful with escaping characters, it can be tricky: *your answer is right*, but the printed results you show are wrong. Your code gives escaped backslashes, which is ok, but you show double-escaped (like it appears in a Playground pane) instead of simple-escaped (like it appears with `print`). Also we have to escape an escape character on SO for it to appear in text or comments. Tricky indeed. ;)

Comment: @EricD. thats really tricky :| (I copy the result from playground)

Comment: updated result comment to result from real `print()`

Comment: no the code with map is wrong, you edit your answer and copy my response(or code in question copied from my response) without knowing how to use map..., map return a new array (here with same type so we could do `inputArray = inputArrat.map {..}`

Comment: @phimage  but when I try in real project, this code do return correct result :(

Answer (score 0):

You can do map on your array and use `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString`

```
let new Array = inputArray.map { 
    $0.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\", withString: "\\\\")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call `enumerate()` on any sequence that is a SequenceType to get the index along with the current item so you can do something like:
`for (index, char) in words.enumerate()`
Although you should also avoid modifying an array while looping it. Think maybe about having another array where you add normal characters to it, and in the case of `\`, you add `\\`