# In Swift, how to remove hashtags in a string?

Tags: swift

For example, a string = `I am a #hashtag1 string #hashtag2 Hi!`

In Swift 2, what's the ideal way to remove the hashtags so the string becomes `I am a string Hi!`

**Hashtags are not fixed strings.** It can be any string that starts with `#`. This question shouldn't be marked as duplicate as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24200888/any-way-to-replace-characters-on-swift-string).

Comment: get an array of strings (using componentsSeparatedByString) which are separated by space, then check each string which starts with #, if so delete them, after that reconstruct again the string sentence

Comment: @azimov Thanks. It's one way I thought of, but I hope to learn more ways to do it (if any).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A solution with regular expression

```
let string = "I am a #hashtag1 string #hashtag2 Hi!"
let withoutHashTags = string.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("#(?:\\S+)\\s?", 
                             withString: "", 
                                options: .RegularExpressionSearch, 
                                  range: Range(string.startIndex..<string.endIndex))
```

---

To remove hashtags without a leading space this slightly altered version can be used. However there is one remaining assumption: The hashtag must be separated from the successive word by a space or is the end of the string.

```
let withoutHashTags = string.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\s?#(?:\\S+)\\s?",
                      withString: " ",
                      options: .RegularExpressionSearch,
                      range: Range(string.startIndex..<string.endIndex))
                      .stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
```

Comment: Very neat and compact. Possibly useful to add as an mutating extension to `String`, `mutating func removeHashTags() { ... }` and just add the above with `string` replaced by `self`. The only possibly drawback here is if the hashtag is not well-separated from the word prior to it, then we'll glue the prior word to the word following the hashtag word, e.g. `"I am gluedTo#hashtag1 ThisNow #hashtag2 Hi!"` yields `"I am gluedToThisNow Hi!"`.

Comment: You can do that with this regex `\\s?#(?:\\S+)\\s?` and replacing with a space character rather than empty string @dfri

Comment: This will fix the "gluing" effect, but still leaves extra spaces if say first or last word is a hashtag word. E.g. `"#hashtag1 one two#hashtag2 three #hashtag3 four #hashtag3"` yields `" one two three four "`.

Comment: I know, there is no simple solution for all cases.

Comment: You are right. I just think this is a such a neat and good answer (already +1:ed) that it would be great to actually present a slightly more exhaustive ( less simple, however making use of your regular expression) solution that cover all cases. Since the OPs question title is very straight forward and search-friendly, such an answer would be valuable in this context. Naturally only if you're up to it, alternatively someone else can make use of you answer and post a more exhaustive general method, but better to wait and see if you want to do this yourself.

Comment: @dfriI updated the answer. The simplest way to get rid of leading or trailing spaces is to trim the string.

Answer (score 1):

Or using `reduce`, but loosing readability:

```
let testString = "I am a #hashtag1 string .#hashtag2 Hi!"

let reducedValue = testString.characters.reduce(("", true)) {

    if $0.1 && $1 != "#" {
        return ("\($0.0)\($1)", true)
    } else if $0.1 && $1 == "#" {
        return ("\($0.0)", false)
    } else if let last = $0.0.characters.last where !$0.1 && $1 == " " && last == " " {
        return ("\($0.0)", true)
    } else if !$0.1 && $1 == " " {
        return ("\($0.0)\($1)", true)
    } else {
        return ("\($0.0)", false)
    }

let result = reducedValue.0
```

Comment: This solution also works as intended for the example in OP:s question, but note that it has the same drawback as noted under vadian:s answer: if the hashtag word is not well-separated from the word prior to it, then the prior word will get glued into the word following after the hashtag.

Comment: @dfri that's true, I update my answer with a slight modification in order to remove the "glue-effect".

Comment: That fixes that issue, but now a "normal" has tag will be replaced leaving double spaces. Also, the solution still leaves a trailing space if a hashtag is the last word in the string (as well as an extra space if hashtag is the first). E.g., `let testString = "#hashtag1 one two#hashtag2 three #hashtag3 four #hashtag3"` yields `| one two three  four |` (for `print("|" + result + "|"): notice the extra initial as well as trailing space, and finally extra space between `three` and `four`.

Answer (score 1):

Oneliner:

```
let text = "I am a #hashtag1 string #hashtag2 Hi!"
let test = text.componentsSeparatedByString(" ").filter { !$0.containsString("#hashtag") }.joinWithSeparator(" ")

print(test) // I am a string Hi!
```

Edit:

Back with a oneliner :p, still a bit too complicated for my taste though.

Comment: What if a hashtag reads "#tagged"? :) See [Hashtag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashtag) on wiki.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below statements:

let aString = "I am a #hashtag1 string .#hashtag2 Hi!"

let newString = aString.replacingOccurrences(of: "#hashtag", with: "")

Comment: are you kidding?