# How can I query parse class for particular object?

Tags: ios, database, swift, parse-platform

In my `ViewController` I have a label which displays the name of a club selected in the previous `ViewController`. I now need to create a query from my parse.com class to retrieve all information on the object that matches the club name displayed as a label. I know how to successfully query parse but I'm finding it hard to find a way to match the query with the label String seeing as the label String can be different depending on what club was selected in the previous view.

Code:

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class MenuController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var clubLabel: UILabel!

    var clubName = String()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        clubLabel.text = clubName
    }
}
```

Previous View already queried parse to populate map with club annotations like so:

```
        let annotationQuery = PFQuery(className: "Clubs")
        annotationQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (clubs, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            // The find succeeded.
            print("Successful query for annotations")
            // Do something with the found objects
            let myClubs = clubs! as [PFObject]
            for club in myClubs {

                //data for annotation
                let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                 let place = club["location"] as? PFGeoPoint
                let clubName = club["clubName"] as? String
                let stadiumName = club["stadium"] as? String
                annotation.title = clubName
                annotation.subtitle = stadiumName
                annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(place!.latitude,place!.longitude)

                //add annotations
                self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
```

Comment: but you already had the object in order to populate the label so what did you do with it? use the existing object...

Comment: what is the more info? how did you get the clubs and why don't those objects hold the data (or relationships to the data) you need ?

Comment: How is your "club label array" from the previous view populated ? If you got it from Parse, why don't you keep the object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using default `MKPointAnnotation`, we will use custom annotations for easier understanding.

---

First we will create a class `ClubAnnotation` conforming to the `MKAnnotation` protocol in a different file.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import Parse

class ClubAnnotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation {

    //MARK: - Instance properties

    let club:PFObject

    //MARK: - Init methods

    init(club:PFObject) {
        self.club = club
    }

    //MARK: - MKAnnotation protocol conformance

    var title: String? { get {       
        return club["clubName"]
        }
    }

    var subtitle: String? { get {
        club["stadium"]
        }
    }

    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D { get {        
        return CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:  club["location"].latitude, longitude: club["location"].longitude)
        }
    }
}
```

I let you handle the error if the fields "stadium", "clubName" or "location" are empty for a Club object, so you can decide how do display it.

---

Then, in your class including the `MKMapView` object (and probably conforming to `MKMapViewDelegate` protocol), replace the handling of your query result :

```
let annotationQuery = PFQuery(className: "Clubs")
annotationQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
    (clubs, error) -> Void in
    if let clubs = clubs where error == nil {
        // The find succeeded.
        print("Successful query for annotations")
        for club in clubs  {
            self.mapView.addAnnotation(ClubAnnotation(club:club))
        }
    } else {
        // Handle the error
    }
}
```

You realize that i don't have to manually set `title`, `subtitle` and `coordinate` properties since your `ClubAnnotation` object returns it directly according to it's implementation of `MKAnnotation` protocol.

Still in this class, add a `selectedClub` property. This property will be used to save the club from the annotation selected and will be passed to the pushed view controller.

```
var selectedClub:PFobject!
```

In your `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` delegate method, you can then get your PFObject from the annotation, and pass it to a new viewController of do everything you want with it, without having to query it from Parse :

```
    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {

    mapView.deselectAnnotation(view.annotation, animated: true)

    if let annotation = view.annotation as? ClubAnnotation {            
       clubSelected = annotation.club
    }
}
```

You now have saved the club object from your custom annotation class, and you have a reference to it. If you want to present or push a new view controller with more information about this club, just override `prepareForSegue` and set this value to the pushed/presented view controller. You don't need to query other fields of your club since they are all loaded according to your Parse request.

Comment: `clubSelected` should be a class property and set it, instead of a local variable. You still need prepareforsegue method in order to pass the `clubSelected` variable to the new view controller. If you need parse data other than club, you will need to do other requests.

Comment: I'll edit my answer for more clarity, wait a little ;)

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a `whereKey` to your `PFQuery`.

```
annotationQuery.whereKey(clubName, equalTo: "clubName")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How are the spaces saved in your database?

Comment: This has always worked for me... Do you have a space in the beginning of your string?

Comment: The string you are trying to put in the whereKey

Comment: Is it possible you could replace spaces with another character i.e "the-club"? You could replace it again when you query the objects. Look at [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24200888/any-way-to-replace-characters-on-swift-string) for replacing characters