# Take out HTML tags from JSON using Alamofire from other viewController

Tags: html, ios, json, swift3

I have a project and I have a table view with JSOn data and then when you click on the cell it takes you to the next view with that data. But for some reason my html tags still come through on the second segue. Do I need to strip out the tags in the second viewController? my code for the second viewController is:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class nextVC: UIViewController {

    var articleImage = UIImage()
    var articleMainTitle = String()
    var articleContent = String()

    @IBOutlet var mainImageView: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet var articleTitle: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var articleContentValue: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        articleTitle.text = articleMainTitle

        mainImageView.image = articleImage

        articleContentValue.text = articleContent

        articleContentValue.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size:12)


    }
}
```

**JSON**

```
{
        posts:      [
             {
        id: “000000”,
        url: "/content/interview2”,
        date: "2016-11-03 09:01:41",
        modified: "2016-11-03 09:03:47",
        title: "An interview",
        image: "https://www.example.com/sites/default/files/o.jpeg",
        content:      {
        value: "<p>Latin text here</p> ",
        format: "filtered_html"
        } 
       ]

}
```

Comment: eradicate HTML TAG by using eplaceoccurrencesofstring

Comment: Where would that go, I am fairly new to Swift?

Comment: give the HTML TAG  and what you want from that.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: log the JSON Data. so that i can understand what you want from that json .

Comment: JSON added its the content i am getting

Comment: so you have problem with         value: "<p>Latin text here</p> ",
want to take out <p></p> just go with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24200888/any-way-to-replace-characters-on-swift-string

Comment: Ok but where would I put that code? top, bottom?

Comment: just check answer. have your problem solved?

Answer (score 1):

Try This.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var yourJsonData:[Int:String] = [1:"<p>Var</p>", 2:"Two", 3:"Three"]

        var someVar = yourJsonData[1]

        someVar = someVar?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("<p>", withString: "")

        someVar = someVar?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("</p>", withString: "")

        print(someVar);

    }
```

Hope it will work

Comment: How would this convert to my code though? This example is using JSON within the file.

Comment: so please be specific it's all what you want. this code will eradicate your HTML Tag. Edit your Question and write what exactly you want

Comment: How would I put that into my code above, thats my question. How does your answer translate to my code??