# Extracting substring from String in iOS Swift

Tags: swift, string

I have created some strings as below:

```
let firstname = ""
let lastname = ""    
let myInfo = "Dana<fname>Dana<lname>CEO<occupation>0123456<hp>01234567<wp>dana@gmail.com<email>"
```

I want to extract certain parts out of that string. For example, I want to assign the part before *`<fname>`* to the `firstname` variable, and  the part before *`<lname>`* to the `lastname` variable.

Comment: look over this: http://www.learnswiftonline.com/reference-guides/string-reference-guide-for-swift/. It may be helpful...

Comment: OMG! im so stupid! Thank you so much for link.

Comment: You're welcome! If you have any other questions related to string trimming feel free to ask!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a fast idea, probably there is some simpler way to do that:

```
let myInfo = "Dana<fname>Dana<lname>CEO<occupation>0123456<hp>01234567<wp>dana@gmail.com<email>"
let components = myInfo.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "<>"))

let values = components.enumerated().filter { $0.offset % 2 == 0 }.map { $0.element }
let keys = components.enumerated().filter { $0.offset % 2 == 1 }.map { $0.element }

var namedValues: [String: String] = [:]

for i in keys.indices {
    namedValues[keys[i]] = values[i]
}

print(namedValues)
```

Then just:

```
let firstName = namedValues["fname"]
let lastName = namedValues["lname"]
```

Comment: this work like a charm. Also, exactly the way i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace occurrences of string with another string to do it.
Example: [Any way to replace characters on Swift String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24200888/any-way-to-replace-characters-on-swift-string)

Comment: I was able to figure it out with componentSeperatedByString. I also have to tweak my string as well. Thank you for your help.