# Replace space with underscore automatically using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, string, swift3

I'm currently coding the sign up part of my app. I would like to replace automatically spaces (in the username) by underscore..

I'm still new with swift and I don't know how to do that.

Currently, the code looks like that:

```
let ACCEPTABLE_CHARACTERS = " ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_."

   func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
      let cs = CharacterSet(charactersIn: ACCEPTABLE_CHARACTERS).inverted
      let filtered: String = (string.components(separatedBy: cs) as NSArray).componentsJoined(by: "")

      return (string == filtered)
}
```

Only characters in %ACCEPTABLE_CHARACTERS% are accepted. I would like to add a line to replace as I said, spaces by "_" directly.

Do you have any idea about how I could do this?

Comment: Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24200888/any-way-to-replace-characters-on-swift-string

Comment: I have seen these questions but I still don't know how to replace it DIRECTLY, in other words, when the user is typing

Comment: Ok I get you. Add an editing changed event and directly set the textfield text.

Comment: I'm sorry. so you want to change the spaces in underscore in the text field while the user is typing?