# Replace first occurrence of the "," in the string with regex

Tags: regex, swift, string

I have a issue with regex pattern. It replace not only "," but also all characters that are before.

I would like to replace first occurrence of the "," to ".":

```
"1,,000.23" -> "1.,000.23"
```

This pattern I am using now :

```
^(.*?),
```

Result that I receive is :

```
"1,,000.23" -> ".,000.23"
```

Expected result :

```
"1,,000.23" -> "1.,000.23"
```

Comment: Why `3` and `5`?

Comment: @user202729 sorry it is typo

Comment: What's a "firt" occurence? (why can't people spell check their questions?)

Comment: It's doing what you're telling it to do. The `.*?` match whatever before the first `,` and you kill it. (I'm not sure, what's your replacement?)

Comment: @user202729 how can I write pattern to replace only singe character ?

Comment: ... spell check please. Try using `\1`.

Comment: Why not use `indexOf(',')` and `subString` and `replace`? It will be easier to reason about and quicker. Regex, if you are unfamaliar with it, causes more problems than it solves.

Comment: What language are you doing this in?

Comment: @Barmar Swift language.

Comment: [any-way-to-replace-characters-on-swift-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24200888/any-way-to-replace-characters-on-swift-string) as alternate way to the (currently 3) answers/comments on how to do it

Comment: @PatrickArtner thx for help but I was searching for regex for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you could use [`^([^,]+),`](https://regex101.com/r/YpreFn/1) and replace with `$1.`

This will capture from the beginning of the string `^` not a comma in a group `([^,]+)` and then match a comma `,`

Answer (score 3):

Use `^(.*?),` and replace it with `$1.`. 
This means:

```
group as less as possible things from line start till first , into group 1
then match a `,` 
and replace it with the captured text of group 1 `$1` and a dot `.`
```

See:  https://regexr.com/3kjdq

Comment: Wouldn't you be better off using a lookbehind?

Comment: @BoristheSpider Ways and rome :) I see already 3 different ones here to achieve the outcome ;) if he specs what regex exactly hes using ...

Answer (score 2):

Copy the capture group to the result. Replace

```
^(.*?),
```

with

```
$1
```

Comment: Wouldn't you be better off using a lookbehind?

Comment: Need to find out what language he's using, so we know which advanced features are available.

Comment: Now that we know he's using Swift, why don't you post the lookbehind answer?