# Swift: how do I go about replacing ʼ with '?

Tags: swift, string

I am trying to parse text and trying to remove some characters.

This doesn't seem to work:

```
string.replacingOccurrences(of: "‘", with: "'")
string.replacingOccurrences(of: "“", with: "\"")
```

Any help is resolving this would be excellent!

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any way to replace characters on Swift String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24200888/any-way-to-replace-characters-on-swift-string)

Comment: Just tested in a playground your first example works just fine, what seems to be problem?

Comment: Its not a duplicate. I know the function that does this. But I am seeing that the string is not being replaced. Hence the question. This is a particular type of smart quote that I want to replace with a "dumb" quote or an apostrophe. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: @Mihir Do you save the results they return?

Comment: So I tried using the playground to see what is wrong and it turns out that the code cant even find this type of quote mark ‘. I am pasting the results below:var `testString = "After the late Arizonanʼs prolonged absence"
var replaced = testString.replacingOccurrences(of: "‘", with: "")
//replaced = replaced.replacingOccurrences(of: "'", with: "")
print(testString)
print(replaced)`
After the late Arizonanʼs prolonged absence
After the late Arizonanʼs prolonged absence

Comment: Be careful. From your current code: The single quote in `testString` is not the same one a the one you are looking for in `replaceOccurences(of:)`. It's `ʼ` vs `‘`. You can do `let first = "ʼ"; let second = "‘"; do for each one: `let firstData = first.data(encoding: .utf8); print("first: \(data as! NSData)")`, you'll see that the result is different.

Comment: @Mihir: Don't put the code into the comments, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Larme This solved the problem. The quotes are different!!! Thank you for solving this!

Answer (score 2):

`String.replacingOccurrences` returns a new instance of the string with the changes made, hence you need to assign and use that new string:

```
string = string.replacingOccurrences(of: "‘", with: "'")
string = string.replacingOccurrences(of: "“", with: "\"")
```

Or, perhaps more in style:

```
string = string.replacingOccurrences(of: "‘", with: "'")
               .replacingOccurrences(of: "“", with: "\"")
```