# How to replace a substring in a string in Swift

Tags: swift

my code is like the following:

```
let fileName = "/users/lezi/downloads/Zootopia.srt"
var srtFile = try? String(contentsOfFile: fileName)
let range = srtFile?.range(of: "00:00:59,825")
print(srtFile?[range!])
srtFile?.replaceSubrange(range!, with: "00:00:59,826")
print(srtFile?[range!])
```

I hope the "00:00:59,825" is replaced to "00:00:59,826", but the print is "Optional("\r\n\r\n2")\n", some characters just before "00:00:59,825"

Comment: Cannot reproduce. A (self-contained) [mcve] is needed.

Comment: What language is the srt file for, maybe this is caused by some encoding issue?

Comment: I can reproduce this with a Chinese srt file, then I also get some garbage in the second `print`. Using `replacingoccurenzces(of:with)` seems to work though so it seems that this should be closed as a duplicate

Comment: @JoakimDanielson: Using `range(of:)` and `replaceSubrange()` should work as well (and is *not* equivalent to `replacingOccurrences(of:with:)`). I think it would be more helpful to figure out why the above code does not work as expected (instead of closing as a duplicate of a question about a different method).

Comment: @MartinR You are right. The `replaceSubrange` function works fine, it is the second `print(srtFile?[range])` statement that doesn't work. If I print the whole file I can see the change. So I guess this then should be closed as "Can not reproduce"?

Comment: srtFile?.replacingOccurrences(of: "00:00:55,775", with: "00:00:59,826")  this code replace nothing,while the following coe  works, let range = srtFile?.range(of: "00:00:55,775")
print(srtFile?[range!])
srtFile?.replaceSubrange(range!, with: "00:00:59,826")

Comment: if I change the substring to "00:00:59,825", both don't work

Comment: Which one of them are you changing so it doesn't work?

Comment: Note that `replacingOccurrences` returns an updated string. The original string stays unchanged, unless you do `srtFile = srtFile.replacingOccurrences(...)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using replacingOccurrences(of:with:).
Returns a new string in which all occurrences of a target string in the receiver are replaced by another given string

sample example :

```
let str = "Swift 4.0 is the best version of Swift to learn, so if you're starting fresh you should definitely learn Swift 4.0."
let replaced = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "4.0", with: "5.0")
```

Comment: Thank you, but if that's the answer, the question is then a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24200888/any-way-to-replace-characters-on-swift-string

Comment: replacingOccurrences and replaceSubrange both works, but the range got before  replaceSubrange seems invalid after replaceSubrange is executed

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of use case. The common syntax to replace the substring is:

```
str.replacingOccurrences(of: "replace_this", with: "with_this")
```

where `replace_this`is the text string you want to replace and ```with_this`` is the new sub-string to insert.

Comment: Thank you, but if that's the answer, the question is then a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24200888/any-way-to-replace-characters-on-swift-string

Comment: Yes.  It is a method of String.NSString not a method of String.  Makes it hard to find!