# Encode NSString for XML using in SOAP

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, soap

I am requesting to a SOAP server, everything is just fine but I have a small issue.

When users type non-English characters like Chinese, Japanese or Vietnamese, I need to encode it.
I have followed this [Encode NSString for XML/HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803676/encode-nsstring-for-xml-html) but not success.

The encoded string is different with this tool http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-escape.html

Anyone has any suggestion?

Comment: `[NSURL URLWithString:[YourString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
`

Comment: I need encode Parameters not URL