# How to convert string to xml in iOS? (objective C, xcode 7.2)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, xcode

I want to convert a NSString variable containing xml codes into xml format. My xml request is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope 
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Body>
        <Authentication xmlns="(namespace link)">
            <Credentials>
                    <Username>username</Username>
                    <Password>password</Password>
            </Credentials>
        </Authentication>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

then i saved this request to a NSString variable. And i got response for this as the server didn't recognize as xml. So how to convert the string i saved into xml?

Comment: Have you tried [https://github.com/nicklockwood/XMLDictionary] this project ?

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/803676/encode-nsstring-for-xml-html

Comment: Thanks Hima and Rahul for your help. I got one more link. And i think it will be a help for others.. https://yuvarajmanickam.wordpress.com/2012/10/17/soap-message-request-and-xmlparsing-in-ios-app/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple code for SOAP request and parsing.

Goto the link: https://yuvarajmanickam.wordpress.com/2012/10/17/soap-message-request-and-xmlparsing-in-ios-app/

or

[github.com/nicklockwood/XMLDictionary](https://github.com/nicklockwood/XMLDictionary.git)

or

[stackoverflow.com/questions/803676/encode-nsstring-for-xml-html](https://stackoverflow.com/q/803676)