# iphone compare &#160; with NSString

Tags: iphone, character-encoding, nsstring, nslog

i was comparing A string coming from XML with another String and results were showing that they are not equal. but in NSLog() both were same  ( e.g. Valore Books ).

then i checked the Source of the XML and i came to know that the actual string is "Valore&#160;Books" and &#160; is infact a space. but the problem is this when i am comparing it with @"Valore Books", it is saying both are not same.

What to Do ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved the problem using a string parsing utility provided by google. Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** I'm replacing my original answer with one that's actually correct for this problem.  Sorry for the initial misunderstanding.

The following line will unescape the html entities in your string.

```
NSString *A = @"Valore&#160;Books";
NSString *B = (NSString *)CFXMLCreateStringByUnescapingEntities(NULL, (CFStringRef)A, NULL);
```

I couldn't find any equivalent function that was higher level, but the performance of this should be excellent.  If I read the docs correctly, you can pass in a CFDictionaryRef as the third argument to specify extra conversions, but it seems that this does a good job doing standard ones on it's own.

Docs are [here](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFXMLTreeRef/Reference/reference.html).

Note that it's probably a good idea to handle the encoding whereever you're pulling those strings into your program at, and not everytime you're comparing.

Also found a second part of this you need to consider.  &#160 isn't just a space, it's a non breaking space, which the above code converts to \312 instead of the standard space.  Those are in fact separate characters in the encoding and when you do a string compare it will fail.

Maybe it'd be easiest to replace #160 with #32 using

```
- (NSString *)stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:(NSString *)target withString:(NSString *)replacement
```

and then running it through the unescape.

It also just occurred to me that the `CFXMLCreateStringByUnescapingEntities` won't be available on the iphone.  [Here is a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659602/objective-c-html-escape-unescape) to an example that shows how to do similar conversions on the iphone.

Comment: `&#160;` is not a percent encoding but an HTML entity. So that method won't help here.

Comment: Fair enough although google searches seem to indicate it would, but I haven't tested it.  I'll give it a shot when I get into my office though.

Answer (score 0):

&#160; is a non-breaking space (Unicode value U+00A0)
The regular space is (in @"Valore Books") has Unicode value U+0020.
So it is not the same character, and the two strings are not equal.