# I am trying to remove escape characters etc from an NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an NSString which has escape characters etc in it.  I need to clean this piece of NSString so that I can display it to the user.  Can anyone help me solve this problem.

It's a bit tricky because its not in HTML format its in escaped HTML format

```
hotel description &lt;B&gt;Description&lt;/B&gt;Friendly and laid-back, the de Alcudia is perfect for a relaxing getaway. Set in pleasant grounds, this complex is about as welcoming as they come. Offering its guests a friendly atmosphere and superbly located on Alcudia's fabulous sandy beach, you can choose to either soak up the sun by the sea, or down on the lovely sunbathing terrace which surrounds the swimming pool. Then, when you're feeling a bit more energetic you can take advantage of the many facilities on offer!&lt;B&gt;Facilities&lt;/B&gt;- Swimming pool - FREE ®sunbeds and parasols - Internet access - Laundry service - WiFi access&lt;B&gt;Meals and Drinks&lt;/B&gt;- Buffet-style restaurant - Show cooking (breakfast and dinner) - Pool bar serving snacks - Lounge bar with satellite TV&lt;B&gt;Activities&lt;/B&gt;- Table tennis - Football - Water polo - Beach volleyball - Billiards&lt;B&gt;Entertainment&lt;/B&gt;- Daily day and evening entertainment - Shows&lt;B&gt;For Children&lt;/B&gt;- Section of the main swimming pool - Hotel kids' club (4-12 years) - Playground - Buggies - Cots&lt;B&gt;Accommodation&lt;/B&gt;One bedroom apartment for up to 4 adults consists of® - Twin room - Lounge area with 2 sofa beds - Kitchenette - Fridge - Coffee maker - Toaster - Satellite TV - Safety deposit box- Bath, shower and wc - 2 ceiling fans - Balcony - Maid service 5 times a week- Sea view apartments available at a supplement®&lt;B&gt;Key Facts&lt;/B&gt;- Opposite the beach - Main resort area: 2 kms- Nearest supermarket: 1 km- 217 rooms - Lifts: 3 - Child age: 2-16 years - Telephone no: 00 34 971- Official rating: 3 key&lt;B&gt;Brochure Name&lt;/B&gt;Aparthotel de Alcudia&lt;B&gt;Key Facts Notes&lt;/B&gt;Some facilities and activities may incur a local charge
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only HTML escaped characters in there are `&gt;` and `&lt;`.  Why not just do a simple search & replace?

If you need something more complicated, try reading this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659602/objective-c-html-escape-unescape).