# How to access google api web services?

Tags: iphone

I'm able to form URL to access Google direction webservice. But when I use optimize factor or when I use "optimize:true|", I get nil in URL. It may be because I am using "|" sign in URL.

How I can fix this?

> NSString *URLAddress=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=%@&destination=%@&waypoints=optimize:true|%@&sensor=false",updated_Address_Of_Source,updated_Address_Of_Destination,updated_Address_Of_Waypoint];
>   NSURL *URL=[NSURL URLWithString:URLAddress];

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you use special characters such as '|' in a URL you must escape them. There's quite a few guides out there on this, but see this stack overflow question: [Objective C HTML escape/unescape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659602/objective-c-html-escape-unescape)

See also http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm.

Comment: That's not how you escape URLs. Go and read some documentation! The link I posted just above would be a good start.

Comment: But in case you're incredibly impatient, the way to encode a pipe in a URL is to use the three characters %7C. Read the docs!

Comment: Also, the pipe isn't the only character in your URL that needs escaping. Check out my second link above for more info about special chars.

Comment: If you found my answer at all useful, please consider accepting it (by clicking the 'tick' at left). This benefits us both!