# NSString encoding special characters like !@#$%^&

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, encoding, nsstring

How can i encode my NSString so all the special character for example & becomes &amp and ' becomes &apos?

I am not sure if encoding is the right word for it so please correct me if I am wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are talking about is called [**HTML Entities**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Entities).

There exists a category claiming to solve this: [NSString+HTML](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser/blob/master/Classes/NSString+HTML.m).

For [**URL Escaping**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) (while we're at it) use this:

```
@nterface NSString (Escaping)

- (NSString *)percentEscapedString
- (NSString *)percentUnescapedString

@end

@implementation NSString (Escaping)

- (NSString *)percentEscapedString {
    return [self stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}

- (NSString *)percentUnescapedString {
    return [self stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}

@end
```

---

**Edit**: As Dave pointed out weaknesses in my references solution, here are some related questions with lots of other solutions:

- [Objective C HTML escape/unescape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659602/objective-c-html-escape-unescape)
- [HTML character decoding in Objective-C / Cocoa Touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105169/html-character-decoding-in-objective-c-cocoa-touch)

Comment: Thanks but is there a better way? because I have to do it for all these string: ~!@#$%^&*()_+=-\][{}|';:> &*()_+=-\][{}|';:"/.,<>? and something it would be very repetitive if i did it for all of these characters

Comment: Updated my answer with a more appropriate category.

Comment: `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` misses a *lot* of stuff.  There are several other answers on this site with alternatives.

Comment: Thanks Dave, added a note along with a few SO links I found.