# ASCII eqivalent of the symbol ampersand (&) in Obj C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, web-services, ascii

I am sending emails from my iPhone app by calling a web service and in the email body I need to send a URL that contains an ampersand symbol (&). If I use the symbol in my URL the web service does not send the email, but if I remove that ampersand symbol everything works and the webservice sends the email just fine. So my question is, should I use the ASCII eqivalent of that symbol ? And if so, what is the ASCII eqivalent for '&'?  Can any one help me?

This is my URL which has the ampersand symbol

```
http://xx.xxx.1.xx/xxx/aspxapprvcontrct.aspx?PartyEMail=xx@xxxx.com&devid= 1xx23
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can try this link i think it helps you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588495/nsstring-encoding-special-characters-like

Comment: @efrank .. you should've posted this as an answer...

Comment: i did the same thing but it is posted as comment.i tried it twice but the same thing happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the whole string (email body) you are sending to your webservice. This question has been asked before on SO, see the link included below. I got it from the link @Caleb included, which in and of itself does not solve your particular problem. I would recommend looking at the second answer posted by @Michael Waterfall.

[Objective C HTML escape/unescape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659602/objective-c-html-escape-unescape)