# iOS special characters conversion

Tags: ios, string, character-encoding

I want to convert `&ugrave;` to `ù` and so on.

I tried to use the following, but it doesn't work.
The original string is

> E Monti nella Trilaterale non c'`&egrave;` pi`&ugrave;`.jpg

I would like to obtain

> E Monti nella Trilaterale non c'è più.jpg

but

```
s = [s stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

gives me

> E%20Monti%20nella%20Trilaterale%20non%20c'`&egrave;`%20pi`&ugrave;`.jpg

while

```
s = [s stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

leaves the original unchanged.
What could I do to convert it?

Comment: Seems like a duplicate, please check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659602/objective-c-html-escape-unescape

Comment: No I don't think it is a duplicate.

Comment: I too think it's a duplicate because you're trying to convert HTML entities into unicode representations. The method `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` converts Unicode strings into (as the name says) [percent encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) strings (for example `<space>` into `%20`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the job!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2843443/396133

```
s = [s stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText];
```