# How to translate HTML entities onto a NSString in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, translation, html

I have a question. My webmethod gives a text back with a lot of HTML entities. You can see an example below.

```
lt;p&gtKRC Genk lanceert een nieuw mini-abonnement voor de 2 resterende thuiswedstrijden in de Europa League. Deze verkoop is enkel voor bestaande abonnees, die nog geen mini-abonnment voor de 3 wedstrijden aankochten.&amp;nbsp;&ltbr &gt;&ltbr &gt
```

Does anybody know how I can translate them in objective-C? I am searching for hours for a solution but don't find anything.

Kind regards.

Comment: I cannot see any HTML or XML attributes at your examlpe text. All I see is
&nbsp;&ltbr >&ltbr &gt

Which are escaped spacial characters

Comment: &lt;p&gt; I mean this. And I want to transform them to breaklines, bold text and so on.

Comment: So you mean you want to HTML-unescape the string?

Comment: Here is how you can unescape HTML entities:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/659631/258539

Comment: That's not attributes, that's entities.

Answer (score 0):

You have problem with HTML escaped characters, these are not HTML markups. You can find the solution here:

[Objective C HTML escape/unescape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659602/objective-c-html-escape-unescape)