# convert html to text or formatted text from an iphone 4 notes backup sqlite file

Tags: iphone, html, webkit, restore

I wanted to restore some of the lost notes that I obtained by using an iTunes backup (of an iphone 4) and opening up the notes.sqlite file.  When I query the table that contains the notes text:

```
select zcontent from znotebody
```

I get the text that is in html format. How can I convert those entries to a more readable content?  It doesnt have to be perfect, just enough to be able to read it. Here is an example of a note:

```html
    Meds fir odd<div>Trazadone</div><div>Effexor (&amp; Cd)</div><div>Buspirone</div><div>Clonodine</div><div>Nortriptyline</div><div>Risperdal</div><div>Straterra&nbsp;</div>
```

Here is the actual note from above:

```html
Meds fir odd
Trazadone
(Effexor & Cd)
Buspirone
Nortriptyline
Risperdal
Straterra<space here>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to retrieve the note text, I would try this

select "" + zcontent + "" 
from znotebody

Then save to a file and open in browser

Answer (score 0):

You have to look some NSString categories, to escape html tags in your text.

Follow this link will help to solve the issue.. [Objective C HTML escape/unescape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659602/objective-c-html-escape-unescape)