# Removing html tags and unwanted characters in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I have the following method to remove the html tags and unwanted characters from a string:

```
-(NSString *) stringByStrippingHTML: (NSString*) s {
NSRange r;
while ((r = [s rangeOfString:@"<[^>]+>" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location != NSNotFound)
    s = [s stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:r withString:@""];
while ((r = [s rangeOfString:@"&#8217;" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location != NSNotFound)
    s = [s stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:r withString:@"\'"];
while ((r = [s rangeOfString:@"&#8221;" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location != NSNotFound)
    s = [s stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:r withString:@"\""];
while ((r = [s rangeOfString:@"&#8220;" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location != NSNotFound)
    s = [s stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:r withString:@"\""];
while ((r = [s rangeOfString:@"&#8230;" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location != NSNotFound)
    s = [s stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:r withString:@"..."];
while ((r = [s rangeOfString:@"&#8211;" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location != NSNotFound)
    s = [s stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:r withString:@"-"];

return s;
}
```

I have too many while cases, how can this be done in a more elegant fashion?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that `NSString` has some built in methods for that.  [Check this answer out.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2843443/2282538)

Comment: I can use what others have made, but I would like to know what can I do in my case for the moment. Thank you for the reply!

Comment: I would add each of your cases to a custom character set, then strip the string based on that character set; instead of having a while loop for each case.

Comment: @TylerAndFriends Character sets wouldn't work in this case because the strings that should be replaced consist of sequences with multiple characters. If you want to replace all occurrences of `&#8211`, you don't want to replace all occurrences of `&`, `#`, `8`, etc., but all occurrences where these characters appear in this specific order.

Comment: I will remember this for the future (and edit my answer), thanks

Answer (score 1):

The [google-toolbox-for-mac](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/) library (yes, this is also for iOS) has some `NSString` category methods for unescaping ampersand-encoded characters more efficiently. Have a look at [GTMNSString+HTML](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/source/browse/trunk/Foundation/GTMNSString%2BHTML.h).

That won't handle the first case (stripping HTML tags), but it should be a faster and more comprehensive solution for the other replacements you're doing.

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't got the expected unwanted characters out. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like `[s stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:"&#8221;" withString:@"\""];` except first case.