# How to convert Casa_Batll%C3%B3 to Casa_Batllȯ(Latin letters)in ios

Tags: ios, nsstring

I would like to convert convert `Casa_Batll%C3%B3` to `Casa_Batllȯ`.

```
NSLog(@"Converting String:%@",[@"Casa_Batll%C3%B3" stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%c3%b3" withString:@"ȯ"]);
```

Using this code, i get only known latin characters or some special characters but not unknown latin characters or special characters. Actually i am getting the string from database which is already created so i don't know about those strings in this database. I have also tried using `NSString+HTML.m` in this [MWFeedParser](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser/blob/master/Classes/NSString+HTML.m). But i didn't get anything. I have also seen these [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659602/objective-c-html-escape-unescape) and [link2](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl). Please help anyone to me.

Comment: If you're referring to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casa_Batll%C3%B3), the last character should be `ó` and not `ȯ`. They're different characters, and the correct one is fully supported in latin charsets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:`.

```
NSLog(@"Converting String:%@",[@"Casa_Batll%C3%B3" stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

Adjust the encoding as appropriate.