# How Can I parse Special characters in XML by obj-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml-parsing

I have an XML tag like

I can parse this element, but I get only the s character in my string.

```
<title>Transport information Classic World&#039;s </title>
```

And I parsed it like this, but in my object I get only the `'s'` character.

```
 if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"title"])
 {
      currentTweet.content = currentNodeContent;
 }
```

How can I decode the whole text in title ?

Comment: Try to get that result in CDATA `<title><![CDATA[Transport information Classic World&#039;s]]</title>`

Comment: So, did u try: `NSString *str = [currentNodeContent stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`  OR  Try with `ASCIIEncoding`

Comment: I tried this, but i have only the 's' character

Comment: So, you have to add `CDATA` when you creating your XML.

Comment: I can't change the XML file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try while you creating `XML` use `CDATA` tags like

```
<title><![CDATA[Transport information Classic World&#039;s]]></title>
```

Also here is a list of [HTML Tags](http://tntluoma.com/sidebars/codes/) and more cases XML with those characters is invalid, unless they are contained within a CDATA.
Also try this [Question hope with help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659602/objective-c-html-escape-unescape/2843443#2843443)

As You asking the you can not change the `XML` so till now you will not resolve i think parser is not able to parse this XML.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the xml file

Comment: I see it, but my XML parser get only one character, not the whole Transport information Classic World&#039;s text! Then i can parset it perfectly!

Comment: @BuntyMadan Please see my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43539307/how-to-post-string-with-special-character-using-xml-parsing-in-objective-c. How can I use your code hear

Answer (score 0):

If you have such possibility, wrap special characters in CDATA tags, when you create this XML.