# stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString improve multiple replacement

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I have this code to replace text to icons.

```
 self.message = [self.message stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(Y)" withString:@"\uE00E"];
    self.message = [self.message stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<3" withString:@"\uE022"];
    self.message = [self.message stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"3>" withString:@"\uE022"];
```

1. Is there a way to do this in one method call ? ( array parameter..for example)
2. If I must call this multiples time, Is there a way to improve memory ? (not creating to much temporary strings)

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any efficient way to replace characters in NSString](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731133/is-there-any-efficient-way-to-replace-characters-in-nsstring)

Comment: Yep, as said in the above link, traversing it like a c-string and manually doing your replacements is fast and in-place

Comment: in that link the code sample is replacing -charcters- with string,
is there code sample to replace strings with strings?

Comment: I suspect creating a local `NSMutableString` copy, using `– replaceOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:` and setting the result is more efficient. At the very least it reduces the the number of property changes (`self.message`) from three to one. Those property changes might be expensive if someone is observing `self.message` using KVO, or if you use cocoa bindings to bind `self.message` to one or more UI elements. Unless you are running that code crazy often, dropping to a C-string like suggested isn't going to buy much other than more complex code!