# Converting encoded characters in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an iOS 7 app that is calling a webservice that returns XML with encoded characters. At first there was only a few of them, so I was just replacing them like so:

```
- (NSString *)convertEncodedCharacters:(NSString *)html
{        
    // Handle escape characters
    html = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&#x2019;" withString:@"'"];
    html = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&#x2018;" withString:@"‘"];
    html = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&#x2014;" withString:@"-"];
    html = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&#x22;" withString:@"\""];
    html = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&#x26;" withString:@"&"];
    html = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&#x3C;" withString:@"<"];
    html = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&#x3E;" withString:@">"];
    html = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&#x2013;" withString:@"–"];
    html = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&#x201C;" withString:@"“"];
    html = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&#x201D;" withString:@"”"];
    html = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&#x201A;" withString:@"‚"];
    html = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&#xA0;" withString:@" "];

    return html;
}
```

But now the content has gotten more complex and I keep running into new characters. Is there a way to just convert all of the encoded characters into human readable ones?

Comment: You can set the encoding to NSUTF8StringEncoding, when the data is received.

Comment: Have a look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659602/objective-c-html-escape-unescape

Comment: Repeatedly calling `stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:` is super wasteful; it's doing an allocation for _every_ entity. You want to [use `NSScanner` for this](https://github.com/woolsweater/NSString-WSSHTMLEntityConversion), or at least use a mutable string.

Comment: cweinberger, that is close, but the encoding is different. Using that code just returns a bunch of new lines and spaces for me.

Comment: cweinberger, actually, that did work once I changed the encoding to NSUTF16StringEncoding. Thank you! If you move your comment to an answer, I will mark yours as correct.

Answer (score 0):

check this class from GitHub, exactly what you are looking for

https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser/blob/master/Classes/NSString+HTML.m