# Displaying Unicode hex-coded character in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, unicode

I am trying to display an Euro symbol coded like that

```
&amp;#x20AC;
```

or

```
&#x20AC (that is what I get when I print the NSString variable containing the symbol code)
```

in ObjectiveC. I tried to use format like "%@" and "%C" but it doesn't work. How can I convert it to displayable form or display that form?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective C HTML escape/unescape](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659602/objective-c-html-escape-unescape)

Comment: `&amp;` and `#x20AC;` are so-called HTML (or XML) character entity references. The "possible duplicate" question has various answers that show how to convert these in an NSString.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
NSString *yourString = @"\u20AC";
```

[image]

Comment: Would be great but I receive that string.