# Data to string encoding: &lt; to <

Tags: ios, objective-c

What type of encoding should I use when converting data from `NSURLSession` response to string in order to get `<` instead of `&lt;` and `>` instead of `&gt;`?

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: Afaik, something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2843445/477878) is still the way to do it. Used to be somewhat troublesome with ARC though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective C HTML escape/unescape](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659602/objective-c-html-escape-unescape)