# iOS : how to get rid of html code such as &#039 and &amp; in a NSString?

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, iphone

I've seen methods on stackoverflow that gets rids of code html tags in between `<>`, but nothing for html code such as &#039 and &amp. Any tips or suggestions will be appreciated.

Edit: This needs to work for iOS 6 as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659602/objective-c-html-escape-unescape

Comment: Checkout NSString+HTML category in this project: https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser