# Obj-c - Remove string from key in multiple dictionaries in array?

Tags: ios, arrays, objective-c

I have an array that contains multiple dictionaries. In each dictionary, sometimes the key 'node_title' contains a value in which an apostrophe is returned as '.

How can I remove ' and replace it with an apostrophe for that key in every dictionary inside my array (self.beautyData)?

**How I'm pulling my data to the array (ViewController.m, viewDidLoad) :**

```
 NSMutableDictionary *viewParams15 = [NSMutableDictionary new];


 [viewParams15 setValue:@"salons_beauty_wellness" forKey:@"view_name"];
 [DIOSView viewGet:viewParams15 success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
     
     self.beautyData = [responseObject mutableCopy];

     
 } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
     NSLog(@"Failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
 }];
```

**Example of the array returned:**

```
2022-05-15 22:26:31.433242-0700 app[26165:11407362] SOME STORES (
        {
        latitude = "49.263";
        longitude = "-123.11";
        nid = 77854;
        "node_title" = "Jon&#039;s Barber Shop";
    },
        {
        latitude = "49.2477";
        longitude = "-123.185";
        nid = 71308;
        "node_title" = "Carla&#039;s Cupcakes";
    
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659602/objective-c-html-escape-unescape maybe?

Comment: If the source is JSON replace the occurrences of `&#039;` with `'` in the JSON string (or even the raw data) and then deserialize the object. If not converting to (JSON) `NSData`, replacing the bytes and converting it back to array might be another way. OMG Objective-C is pretty cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert json to **Codeable** Objects and in

```
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {}
```

you need to get value of **node_title** and then replace with your desired result and save again with this varible then you will get proper result

Example:
struct DataObjets : Codable {

```
   let node_title : String?

   enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
     case node_title = "node_title"
   }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        var tmp_node_title = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: . node_title)
    tmp_node_title = tmp_node_title.repplace("&#039;", "'")
     node_title =  tmp_node_title
   }
}
```